# Git - Clone Repositories in Bulk

Tags: git, bitbucket

I just joined a company that has a git server (hosted through bitbucket), which has about 80 projects which have multiple repositories under each project (lets say 5 for easy math). Is there an easy way to recursively clone all 400 of these repositories?

Comment: Found the following so far, which looks to be an api for bitbucket... http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 2):

You will have to script hat yourself.

You can get a [list of the repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repositories-endpoint-423626330.html) from the BitBucket API. Then just loop through them an clone each one.